# How can I unlink a windows folder with spaces?

Tags: perl

I am trying to remove files and folders that do not match our naming standard. Well I can seem to loop through an array of collected files and folders that do not match and delete them. The problem I am running into is I cannot remove files that have spaces in them. I am running on Windows with Strawberry Perl.

Here is a sample of the array

```
Picture.jpg
Sample Document.doc
New Folder
```

The only thing I can delete successfully is `Picture.jpg` in this example.

Here is the function

```
foreach my $folder (@$returned_unmatches) {
    print "$folder\n";
    remove_root_junk($office,$folder);
}
```

Here is the subroutine.

```
sub remove_root_junk {

my $office = shift;

my $folder = shift;

my $order_docs_path = $office_names{$office};

unlink "$order_docs_path\\$folder";
```

}

`$order_docs_path` is just the full path up to where I am working. In this case `C:\Data\Locations\Canton\Order_Documents` if this help at all.

Answer (score 3):

Under normal circumstances, directly unlinking a directory is not supported. The documentation for [`unlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) says:

> Note: `unlink` will not attempt to delete directories unless you are superuser and the **-U** flag is supplied to Perl. Even if these conditions are met, be warned that unlinking a directory can inflict damage on your filesystem. Finally, using `unlink` on directories is not supported on many operating systems. Use [`rmdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rmdir.html) instead.

If your subdirectory is not empty, the `rmdir` documentation suggests using `rmtree` in [File::Path](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html).

Comment: Of course you would continue to use `unlink` for regular files.

Comment: +1 `use File::Path;` `rmtree` would remove plain files as well.